# How do you prevent a button from getting smaller, when changing from a div to a button?

Tags: html, css, button

I have no idea what would fix this.

https://jsfiddle.net/eL5gn73s/

That big one is a div, the small ones are the buttons that have shrunk.

The button should be the same size as the div, not the other way around.

After changing from a div to a button, the button shrunk smaller than the size of the div that was 47px.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.box.box2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="box box2" type="button"></button>
<button class="box " type="button"></button>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them both a `display:block` (or `inline-block`) and add `box-sizing:content-box` to both, then add `box-sizing` to both (`border-box`)

As for a FULL answer: this has to do with the `border-box` and `content box` which differs from `div` to `button`

Button uses the smaller and div the larger.

```
content-box uses the size + padding + borders
border-box uses size + padding - borders
```

SO your 4px X 2 border-radius has to be added TO the button to make it the same size as the div.

Here I show both the fixed and then the original for comparison (all as inline-block just for visual)  Notice the first group is the same size as the second groups DIV.

Hopefully this gives a better explanation and how to "fix" it.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button.exit,
div.exit,
div.exit-new,
button.exit-new {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

div.exit-new,
button.exit-new {
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
}

div.exit {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  top: 4px;
}

button.exit {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

/*add element just for specificity here */
button.exit,
div.exit,
div.exit-new,
button.exit-new {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.exit.exitPage2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="exit exitPage2" type="button"></button>
  <button class="exit " type="button"></button>
  <div class="exit"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div>originals</div>
  <button class="exit-new" type="button"></button>
  <button class="exit-new" type="button"></button>
  <div class="exit-new"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @C.BoyntonGlick It's not clear what you want (this is a good answer)

Comment: I added more details with visual to hopefully give a better answer.

Answer (score -1):

try editing the buttons in the .exitpage2 css like this

```
.exit.exitPage2 {
  background: red;
   width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

it should do what you need it to if you set the height and width to the desired amounts